# Как реализовать выдачу файла по ссылке в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

В общем, надо что бы при переходе по ссылке открывался диалог с ботом и бот сразу отправлял определенный файл. (для каждого файла своя ссылка) Вот и думаю как такие ссылки делаются! Aiogram

Answer (score 0):

Очень размыто описано, поэтому попробую угадать, что Вы имели ввиду.
При переходе по ссылке, если я правильно понял, у Вас должно открыться стартовое меню с ботом, чтобы начать работать с ботом нужно, чтобы пользователь нажал кнопку "старт" или отправил команду /start. И тут Вы в ответ на эту команду можете отправить ему файл или сообщение и файл.
Про отправку файлов с помощью Aiogram посмотрите [тут](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/file.html) и [тут](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/input_file.html)

Comment: Почти в точку, только при нажатию на кнопку старт выдаётся всегда разные файлы (какая-то уникальная ссылка создаётся), если пользователь уже разговаривал с ботом то команда стар не нажимается, просто после перехода по ссылке бот выдает файл без лишних сообщений.

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю задачу. Давайте попробуем разложить её на простые шаги.
Есть бот, заходит в него пользователь, нажимает старт, что потом должно произойти? По какому принципу будет определяться уникальность файла и ссылки на него? Если всё это расписать пошагово, то может быть придет понимание тогда.

Comment: Есть канал в телеграмме, в канале вылаживаются программы с ссылкой на бота. При клике на ссылку бота, бот без сообщений либо с командой старт (если пользователь первый раз запустил бота) выдает файл.